# Poetry add dependency within docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, pycharm, python-poetry

I am new to docker and poetry but are currently working in a project which contains both.

**Problem:**

I am unable to add new dependencies via poetry to the docker-compose container.

**Description:**

In pycharm I use docker-compose as my interpreter for a django project where poetry is used to manage the dependencies. I can access the django-project via localhost, so it seems to work.

**What I tried:**

The [poetry documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add) states the following example:

```
poetry add requests pendulum
```

But when I execute this command in the pycharm terminal it states, that python wasn't found.
My expectation was that I can install a dependency via the CLI which is then managed by poetry and the poetry.lock and pyproject.toml are then updated.

**Question:**

How can I add new dependencies, or even access the CLI within docker compose to execute the above command?

**Update:**

I was able to install the dependency by:

writing in the terminal:

1. `docker compose down`
2. inserting dependency into the pyproject.toml
3. `docker compose run --rm django poetry lock --no-update`
4. `docker compose build django`

But still unable to access a CLI where I can execute poetry commands directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi this is pretty old but you should use the Dockerfile i.e `RUN poetry add..` the dockerfile can be specified within compose